# Java RMI port binding error in openshift

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, rmi, openshift

I have developed a small Spring based web application to test Spring RMI. There I have created a simple service to generate a greeting message based on the input parameter and return it back to the client. My spring context file looks like this:

```
<bean id="registry" 
class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean">

  <property name="port" value="4777"/>

</bean>

<bean id="greetingService" class="com.greeting.GreetingServiceImpl" >
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter"
      p:service-ref="greetingService"
      p:serviceName="greetingRmiService"
      p:serviceInterface="com.greeting.GreetingService"
      p:registry-ref="registry"
/>
```

First I have deployed this application in my local pc running tomcat server 7 and it deployed successfully.
Then I have uploaded the war file of this application to Openshift tomcat 7 DIY server. But It doesn't deploy my application and gave this error in the log file.

`SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'registry' defined in ServletCo
ntext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.rmi.serve
r.ExportException: Port already in use: 4777; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowir
eCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanReg
istry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListab
leBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractAppl
icationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1100)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1618)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 4777; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:328)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:236)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:207)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:123)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.(RegistryImpl.java:109)
    at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:203)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:267)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:236)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:193)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAuto
wireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowir
eCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied`

How to fix this error and getting deployed this application in Openshift?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Port already in use: 4777

Use a port that isn't already in use.

OR make your sure application is really stopped before you restart it.

Comment: I have run "netstat a | grep $OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP" to check currently running ports. but port 4447 was not there. And also i have tried different ports randomly as well(1099,9999 etc). but they didnt work. its not practical that try all the different ports. Did you see **Permission denied** exception. so i guess this is about permission for port binding in openshift server. any idea about that?

Comment: The port number in the error message is 4777, but 'permission denied' means you need to set a Windows Firewall rule.

Comment: thanks for your help! yes, may be firewall is the problem. but I don't think that we have permission to change firewall settings in openshift server as a user.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenShift it is possible to bind to the internal IP with port range: 15000 - 35530. So, you can't use 4477. Use anything between 15000-35530. Also, understand that these are internal ports which means you can  only use them from within application. Read more at https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port

Comment: but I have also tried several ports between port range: 15000 - 35530 after this and i got the same result(java.net.BindException: Permission denied). yes i know i can't access those ports externally. but first i want to deploy my application successfully. Then i have to find out a way to forward my rmi port to externally accessible port.